# guard runs specs three times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, guard

After wondering why my specs do get run couple times after upgrading to **guard 2.0.3** and **guard-rspec 3.1.0** 
(running linux and vim)
i could reproduce the strange behavior by creating a fresh barebones rails4-application, included

- gem 'rspec-rails'
- gem 'guard'
- gem 'guard-rspec'

to the Gemfile

created a vanilla Guardfile:

```
bundle exec guard init
```

fired up guard:

```
bundle exec guard --debug
```

when changing a e.g. app/models/foobar.rb

the specs run three times:

```
13:27:58 - DEBUG - Trying to run Guard::RSpec#run_on_additions with ["spec/models/foobar_spec.rb"] 
13:27:58 - DEBUG - Hook :run_on_changes_begin executed for#  
[...] 
13:27:58 - INFO - Running: spec/models/foobar_spec.rb
[...] 
13:28:00 - DEBUG - Trying to run Guard::RSpec#run_on_removals with ["spec/models/foobar_spec.rb"] 
13:28:00 - DEBUG - Hook :run_on_changes_begin executed for # 
[...] 
13:28:00 - INFO - Running: spec/models/foobar_spec.rb
[...] 
13:28:01 - DEBUG - Trying to run Guard::RSpec#run_on_modifications with ["spec/models/foobar_spec.rb"] 
13:28:01 - DEBUG - Hook :run_on_changes_begin executed for # 
[...] 
13:28:01 - INFO - Running: spec/models/foobar_spec.rb
[...]
```

when simulating a file change with

$guard(main)> change app/models/foobar.rb

it runs - as expected - just once:

```
13:48:52 - DEBUG - Trying to run Guard::RSpec#run_on_modifications with ["spec/models/foobar_spec.rb"]
13:48:52 - DEBUG - Hook :run_on_changes_begin executed for #
[...]
13:48:52 - INFO - Running: spec/models/foobar_spec.rb
[...]
```

anybody is experiencing the same problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a guard-rspec issue. See: https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/495